# Python Akamai Sensor Data Generation with valid Cookie abck

Tags: python-3.x, akamai

I am trying to send twice post request to www.footlocker.it

```
sess = requests.session()
print("start-Point")
bot = BotDetector()
payload = "{\"sensor_data\":\"" + bot.generatesensordata() + "\"}"
d = sess.post(url_ak, headers=headers_ak, data=payload, verify=False, timeout=15)
bot.cookie = sess.cookies["_abck"]
payload = "{\"sensor_data\":\"" + bot.generatesensordata1() + "\"}"
d = sess.post(url_ak, headers=headers_ak, data=payload, verify=False, timeout=15)
print('Status code {},'.format(d.status_code))
print('Header {},'.format(d.headers))
```

Target is for getting valid cookie abck and success true as status code.
I have write some custom code for botdetector. But i can't bypass with good result.

Comment: when i send get request instead of first post request, i get success: true and not valid abck.
and when i remove first post request and use only 2nd post request, i get success: false and valid abck.
My target is for getting success : True and valid cookie abck.

Comment: do you find a solution? i have success true but no cookie in response headers

Answer (score 0):

it means your sensor data is bad most likely. take a look at the akamai script for the site & compare it to what you have now.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But it is not solution. I want you to help me to solve that issue